# Polymer/PolymerTS: Pass object to custom element

Tags: typescript, polymer

I'm currently creating a web app that uses Typescript instead of Javascript to see how Typescript feels. I also am learning Polymer to kill two birds with one stone. To get this working, I'm using [PolymerTS](https://github.com/nippur72/PolymerTS) to get this to work, and up until this point it's been working just fine. However, I've hit a barrier.

I have two elements, we can call them 'my-foo' and 'my-bar':

```
<link rel="import" href="path/to/my-bar.html">

<dom-module id="my-foo">
    <template>
        <my-bar myBarProperty="{{myFooProperty}}"></my-bar>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Now the value 'myFooProperty' is a value that has been deserialized from JSON into a custom Typescript class. I can get all its properties to display if I data-bind them, e.g.

```
<h1>{{myFooProperty.name}}</h1>
```

But passing it into the second custom element does not work, i.e. "myBarProperty" is null or an empty map. The element is loaded correctly (any html not data-specific is loaded and displayed) but the value itself isn't set. Any insight on why this is? Maybe this isn't possible?

Relevant *.ts files:

my-foo.ts:

```
@component("my-foo")
class MyFoo extends polymer.Base {
    @property({ type: Object, notify: true })
    myFooProperty: any;

    constructor() {
        super();
        apiCallThatReturnsPromise().then(value => {
            this.myFooProperty = value;
        });
    }
}

MyFoo.register();
```

my-bar.ts:

```
@component("my-bar")
class MyBar extends polymer.Base {
    @property({ type: Object, notify: true, value: function() { return {}; } })
    myBarProperty: any;
}

MyBar.register();
```

**Edit 1**: I did see if not deserializing the JSON and passing just the raw data would fix my problem, but it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `my-bar-property`.

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping

Comment: Thank you... My god this was such an easy fix! I need to read more on Polymer I suppose.